# What's the difference between 大哥 and 大哥哥?

Tags: difference

I know them both means big bother. Though there are differences somehow.

> 小明，谢谢这位给你让座的大哥哥。

Comment: 大哥 means: 1. The eldest brother in one's peers. 2. The boss of a gang. The address of reiterative diction in Chinese, like 哥哥, is often used by kids or juniors, compared to 哥. If the style is used in persons' name, it makes a nickname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring someone as 大哥哥 (big brother) to a kid is not unlike referring a "狗" (dog) as "狗狗" (doggy) to a child. It is a kind of 'baby/ kid talk'

大哥 is a proper term for "big brother". Just like in English, depend on context, 大哥 (big brother) can mean your own elder brother, your lover, a stranger who is older than you or about  the same age as you and so on

Comment: In Triad lingo, '大哥' can mean a gang leader too :-)

Answer (score 0):

"大哥" normally refers to a family member such as an older bother or older cousin.
"大哥哥" is broadly used when calling any young male but older than you and not a relative.

Answer (score 0):

大哥 and 大哥哥 can have a lot of different meanings, but in your context

> 小明，谢谢这位给你让座的大哥哥。

*这位* ...大哥哥, so 大哥(哥) is a stranger

The differences between 大哥 and 大哥哥 in this context is the age difference.
大哥哥 here probably looks under 25-ish years old, and seemingly a friendly person.
大哥 if used here would refers to any adults who are older than 小明